# minimize_blockmodel_dl with weighted graph

Tags: python, graph-tool

I am trying to use `minimize_blockmodel_dl` to identify communities in a weighted (undirected) graph.

I found out that this method [once supported](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/issues/225) a `eweight` parameter, but it doesn't anymore.

Is there any method in graph-tool nowadays which takes into account weights *and* automatically looks for the optimal number of components?

Answer (score 2):

This is described in detail in the documentation: https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/demos/inference/inference.html#edge-weights-and-covariates

(Also, the `eweight` parameter is still there, it is only accessed differently. However, this parameter always meant edge multiplicities, not arbitrary weights. The link above describes how to incorporate arbitrary weights, which can be real, signed, etc.)